# Caret nnet: logloss not working for twoClassSummary

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret

I have a training dataset

```
    Out  Revolver   Ratio     Num ...
0   1    0.766127   0.802982  0   ...
1   0    0.957151   0.121876  1 
2   0    0.658180   0.085113  0 
3   0    0.233810   0.036050  3 
4   1    0.907239   0.024926  5
```

The outcome variable `Out` is binary and only takes on the values 0 or 1. `Num` is not a factor

I then attempted to run `nnet` using `caret`. I want to eventually try `nnGrid` but I just want to make sure this works first:

```
nnTrControl=trainControl(method = "cv", classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, 
    number = 2,verboseIter = TRUE, returnData = FALSE, returnResamp = "all") 
#nnGrid = expand.grid(.size=c(1,4,7),.decay=c(0,0.001,0.1))

Outf<-factor(training$Out)
model <- train(Outf~ Revolver+Ratio+Num, data=training, method='nnet',
           trControl = nnTrControl, metric="logLoss")#, tuneGrid=nnGrid)
```

I get the error

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X0, X1 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).
```

However, I've used `caret` and gotten this error before, which I resolved by using `make.names`. So when I try the below instead:

```
yCat<-make.names(training$Out, unique=FALSE, allow_=TRUE)
mnn <- model.matrix( ~Revolver + Ratio + Num, data = training)
model <- train(y=yCat, x=mnn, method='nnet',
           trControl = nnTrControl, metric="logLoss")#, tuneGrid=nnGrid)
```

I then get the message

```
The metric "logLoss" was not in the result set. ROC will be used instead.
```

But I don't understand why its not evaluating according to `logLoss`?

If I then use this to predict on a test set

```
probs<-predict(model, newdata=testSet, type="prob")
```

I get

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '(Intercept)' not found
```

How do I fix this?